# Wordpress Contact form 7 redirect delay

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

i'm using the Contact form 7 Redirect, when a new user signs up.
When the user signs up a message is displayed, but the redirect happens instant, so there is no time to read the message.

Is there a way to delay the redirect with Javascipt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deactivate the **plugin** that you're using for `form submission redirect`.

put it on `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'prefix_my_footer_scripts' );
function prefix_my_footer_scripts(){
  ?>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', setTimeout(function( event ) {
        location = 'http://example.com/';
    }, false ), 1000); // Replace location and 1000(ms) as your wish
    </script>

  <?php
}
```

[see more](https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me. It fired on page load. So i wrote it like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_footer_scripts' );
function load_footer_scripts(){
    ?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {

            setTimeout(function( event ) {
                location = 'http://example.com/';
            }, 4500 );

        }, false );
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Contact Form 7's Custom DOM Event to achieve this. You need to replace the http://example.com/ in the code to the URL you want to redirect to.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'http://example.com/';
}, false );
</script>
```